# Unable to convert object dtype into duration of format mm:ss:ms with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column with a time duration. This column is of type Object. The values look like this:

```
    55:59.9
    51:10.6
    41:19.1


from datetime import datetime
test = datetime.strptime(df.column, '%M::%S::%MS.%f')

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

I tried datetime commands for Pandas but they don't work! Can someone please assist, so I can convert this column into duration (mm:ss:ms) and then conduct subtractions?

Thanks!

Comment: add the code u used, with the error msgs if any

Comment: @sammywemmy just did.

Comment: have a look again at ur data, it is not possible to have 69 seconds ... the last entry. the assumption here is that ur data is ```minute:seconds.microseconds```

Comment: @sammywemmy that was a typo as I manually added the values...

Comment: ```pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], format='%M:%S.%f')``` try this let's c,

Comment: @sammywemmy still error: ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

Comment: use `pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['column'])`?

Comment: try @QuangHoang suggestion. Is ur data entirely mm:ss:ms? or do u have hours and some other details included?